# Get data between two date from sql server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

I  want to get all data between two dates from sql server with using mssql and query of sequelize in nodejs.

Start and End dates come from react frontend with axios.post.
For example start date is `2021-01-04T08:53:00.000Z` and end date is `2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z`  in express.

```
app.post('/getData', function (req, res) {
  let startTime=req.body.start
  let endTime=req.body.end

  sequelize.query(` select Date_Time from S001T01  where Date_Time between ${startTime} and ${endTime}`, {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
  }).then(result => {
    console.log(result)
})

});
```

It returns many error, one of them is  `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Invalid column name '2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z 23:59:00'.`.

In table viewer Date_Time column shown like that

[image]

I don't know what should I do.

Thanks for help.

Comment: In sql, double quotes are used for identifiers, single quotes are used for literal strings and dates

Comment: I changed the query but there are still errors. `Executing (default): select Date_Time from S001T01  where Date_Time between 2021-01-04T08:53:00.000Zand 2021-01-04T21:00:00.000Z
(node:2576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Incorrect syntax near 'T08:'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a wrong datetime format. `2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z 23:59:00` doen't correspond to the traditional [ISO 8601](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

If you want all entries between `2021-01-04T08:53:00.000Z` and `2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z`, your SQL query should look like this :

```sql
select Date_Time from S001T01  where Date_Time between 2021-01-04T08:53:00.000Z and 2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z
```

You should also consider using modified datetime instead on concatenation.

Maybe something like thing should do the job :

```js
var dt = new Date();
dt.setHours( dt.getHours() + 2 );
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: Hey, thank for answer but, I am still getting this error. `Executing (default): select Date_Time from S001T01  where Date_Time between 2021-01-04T08:53:00.000Z and 2021-01-05T21:00:00.000Z
(node:12684) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Incorrect syntax near 'T08:'.`

Comment: Have you tried another datetime format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` instead of the ISO 8601 format ? I can read on a forum that, in order to make a query between two dates, the format should be like the one i mentioned above. `SELECT * FROM T_DATES_TDT WHERE TDT_DATE BETWEEN '2006-04-8' AND '2006-04-8 23:59:59.999'`

Comment: Yes, I have tried `select * from S001T01  where Date_Time between 2021-01-04 21:44:00 and 2021-01-04 22:03:00` but result was the same. It always thrown ` Incorrect syntax near '21'.`

Comment: It might be ok if you put quotes between dates value. `select * from S001T01  where Date_Time between '2021-01-04 21:44:00' and '2021-01-04 22:03:00'` [forum link](https://baptiste-wicht.developpez.com/tutoriels/microsoft/sql-server/datetime/)